# No products available for purchase - In App Purchase

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to set up an in-app purchase for my Unity project and I have enough experience in this but this time it is not working and I don't know why!

I want to share more information with you so you can guide me into this.

This is my setup at Apple store account:

[image]

This kind of debug log I have from XCode:

[image]

I have followed this Unity document to setup:

[Unity IAP](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/unity-iap#)

Also for testing in-app purchase, I have submitted build to Testflight but still in downloaded build in-app purchase not working.

What is wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any contracts which are pending? All the contracts/agreements are to be agreed before testing IAPS

Comment: Let me check the agreement section regarding this

Comment: Paid Apps agreement was pending - this is my customer's account so I don't have information about this